# Difficulty implementing redux thunk

Tags: redux, react-hooks, redux-thunk

This is my first time working with redux hooks and I keep receiving the error: "Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions."

I have added the middleware thunk. Following the other peoples questions, I am not sure where I am making the mistake. I'm looking for an explanation on what I am doing wrong and what I should be reading in order to fix it.

Actions:

```
export const fetchNewsData = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        axios.get('http://localhost:3001/getnews')
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data);
                
                const data = response.data;
                dispatch(loadNews(data));
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);

                dispatch(errorOnNews(error));
            });
    }
}

export const loadNews = (fetchedData) => {
    return {
        type: LOAD_NEWS,
        payload: fetchedData
    }
}

export const errorOnNews = (errorMessage) => {
    return {
        type: ERROR_ON_NEWS,
        payload: errorMessage
    }
}
```

Reducer:

```
const initialState = {
    fetched: false,
    data: [],
    input: '',
    filtered: [],
    error: ''
}

const newsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case LOAD_NEWS:
            return {
                ...state,
                fetched: true,
                data: action.payload
            }

        case FILTER_NEWS:
            return {
                ...state
            }

        case ERROR_ON_NEWS:
            return {
                ...state,
                error: action.payload
            }
        
        default: return state;
    }
}
```

Store:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './rootReducer';
const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

Component:

```
const fetch = useDispatch(fetchNewsData());

useEffect(() => {
        if(hasFetched){
            // work on true condition
        } else {
            fetch(); // fails on this line.
        }
    }, []);
```

Comment: You'll need to include more details, as the only reason you should be getting the message ""Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions." is if you haven't connected the redux-thunk middleware.

Comment: I installed thunk through the npm, included the import into the file that has the store. In The component is nested in another component that has the provider that is passing the imported store. Based on the write up on npm and github for thunk, I didn't think there where any other components to making this work. I have added the imports for the store, but besides posting my whole code, which is alot, I'm not sure what else I can do. Should I just post whole thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useDispatch` does not work like this, as it ignores all arguments and just returns you a `dispatch` function. So you have called `dispatch()` there, which essentially equals `dispatch(undefined)` - and the store doesn't know what to make of that action.

Do this instead:

```js
const dispatch = useDispatch();

useEffect(() => {
        if(hasFetched){
            // work on true condition
        } else {
            dispatch(fetchNewsData()); // fails on this line.
        }
    }, []);
```

Also, generally you are writing a very outdated style of redux here that we do not really recommend to learn or use in new applications any more.
You might have been following an outdated tutorial - as this style requires you to write multiple times the necessary code and is much more error prone.

For up-to-date tutorials featuring modern redux with the official redux toolkit please see [the official redux tutorials](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts)

Answer (score -1):

Was following a tutorial and creating additional work that was unnessessary. Answer is to:

Cut: `const fetch = useDispatch(fetchNewsData());`

Change: `fetch();` to `fetchNewsData();`

In this case, I am calling a handling function that will execute the dispatches when required.

Comment: This is misleading, `useDispatch` does not accept any parameters.

Comment: Yes, I realized to late that I did not understand how to use dispatch. I followed phry's advice and just started to read the official tutorials.